# Cant parse a dictionary retrieved from xmlhttprequest.responseText [SOLVED]

Tags: javascript, python, json, xmlhttprequest

In my program, I make a call to my python script to return a dictionary. I am trying to access this dictionary in JavaScript after completing the XMLHttpRequest. response text. The dictionary will appear however, I am not able to parse it.

For example: calling this,responseText['Username']; returns undefined

I have tried stringifying the responseText and then parsing it, which hasn't helped at all. What am I doing wrong? I have been stuck on this for too long

Requested function:

```
def getBasicInfo():
    dict = {}
    list = []
    username = ud["username"]
    displayName = ide["displayName"]
    accountCreationDate = ud['creationTime']
    following = fol["followingUsersCount"]
    followers = fol['followerCount']
    playlistCount = len(ply["playlists"])
    playlists = ply["playlists"]

    dict.update({"Username": username})
    dict.update({"Display Name": displayName})
    dict.update({"Account Creation Date": accountCreationDate})
    dict.update({"Following": str(following)})
    dict.update({"Followers": str(followers)})
    dict.update({"Number of playlists": str(playlistCount)})

    for x in range(0, len(ply["playlists"])):
        list.append(playlists[x]["name"])

    dict.update({"Playlist names": list})
    totalNumberSongs = len(sh1) + len(sh2) + len(sh3)
    firstTime = sh1[0]['endTime']
    lastTime = sh3[-1]['endTime']
    dict.update({"Total Number of Songs Analyzed": str(totalNumberSongs)})
    timeStamp = firstTime + " to " + lastTime
    dict.update({"Data Lifecycle": timeStamp})
    return dict
```

Python Script:

```
#!\Users\bobs\anaconda3\python.exe         #Python Interpreter
from data import *
import cgi
import sys

fs = cgi.FieldStorage()

sys.stdout.write("Content-Type: application/json")
sys.stdout.write("\n")
sys.stdout.write("\n")

if "basic" in fs.keys():
    info = getBasicInfo()
    print(info)

if "artist" in fs.keys():
    artist = countArtistsDesc()
    print(artist)

if "song" in fs.keys():
    song = countSongsDesc()
    print(song)

if "day" in fs.keys():
    day = getHighestPlayedDays(True)
    print(day)

if "playlist" in fs.keys():
    playlist = getPlaylist()
    print(playlist)

sys.stdout.write("\n")
sys.stdout.close()
```

HTML Page/XMLHTTPRequest:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Basic Info</title>
</head>
<body style="background-color:#1DB954">
<h1 align="center">User's Basic Info</h1>
<script>
    var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    http.open('GET', '/cgi-bin/simpleData.py?basic=True', true);
    http.setRequestHeader('content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    // http.responseType = 'json'
    http.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("responseText").innerHTML = this.responseText;
            document.getElementById("problem").innerHTML = this.responseText['Username'];
        }
    };
    http.send(null);
</script>
<p id="responseText"></p>
<p id="problem"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Output:

```
{'Username': 'bobsmith123', 'Display Name': 'Bob Smith', 'Account Creation Date': '2016-10-10', 'Following': '34', 'Followers': '46', 'Number of playlists': '32', 'Playlist names': ['5th Dimension', 'Dumb Chilling', 'Rock v2 / Nu Metal', 'Party ', 'Rap', 'Pumping Iron', 'Aggression', 'Soundcloud 4', 'Oldies but Goodies', 'Chopped and Screwed', 'Cruel Winter', 'Soundcloud', 'Halloween 2020', 'Trap Christmas', "80's Night", 'EDM', 'Life of Pablo Tour', 'Igor Tour', 'Thugger', 'Playboi Carti', 'Cactus Jack', "WAKE UP MR WEST, OH HE'S UP", 'Future', 'Denzel', 'LORDE PRETTY FLACKO JOYDE', 'AstroWorld ', 'Daytona Tour', 'Children of the Korn', 'Rock', 'Classics', 'Floyd', 'Chill Rock'], 'Total Number of Songs Analyzed': '27334', 'Data Lifecycle': '2020-01-24 19:37 to 2021-01-25 20:52'}

undefined
```

Solution:

```
#Very end of getBasicInfo()
return json.dumps(dict, separators=(',', ':'))
#After readyState == 4 && this.status == 200 in the HTML page
parsed = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
```

Comment: The response is text, not a dictionary. So, you need to parse the string back into an Object with `JSON.parse(responseText)`.

Comment: @ScottMarcus thanks for the quick reply, whenever I do that nothing appears at all. I figured it wouldnt need parsed since I specified the content type to be json in the script file. I have tried parsing and stringifying and neither of them seems to help

Comment: Stringifying is useless since you already have a string. JSON is a string. It needs to be parsed. I would start by just doing this `console.log(responseText)` and posting exactly what this is in your question.

Comment: Ok, that means that the JSON string that is being returned is not correct and so the attempt to parse it back into an object is failing. JSON.parse() is the right thing to do, but your Python script needs to be corrected to produce proper JSON.

Comment: `{'Username': 'bobsmith123', ....`  is not JSON. JSON requires double quotes.

Comment: @ScottMarcus With json.parse() my console output is the exact same as the first line of output in the question,, however it still does not show on the webpage.

Comment: Showing on the page is not the same thing as what your question seems to be asking about. What happens if you log: `JSON.parse(responseText)["Username"];`?

Comment: @ScottMarcus thanks alot! My fix that worked was to return the dict as json.dumps(dict, separators=(',', ':')) and then parse the responseText. Thanks again \m/

Answer (score 0):

This is because python represents strings with single quotes, and json requires double quotes.

```py
import json;
body = {'Username': 'bobsmith123', 'Display Name': 'Bob Smith', 
        'Account Creation Date': '2016-10-10', 'Following': '34', 
        'Followers': '46', 'Number of playlists': '32',
        'Playlist names': [
            '5th Dimension', 'Dumb Chilling', 'Rock v2 / Nu Metal', 'Party ', 'Rap', 
            'Pumping Iron', 'Aggression', 'Soundcloud 4', 'Oldies but Goodies', 
            'Chopped and Screwed', 'Cruel Winter', 'Soundcloud', 'Halloween 2020', 
            'Trap Christmas', "80's Night", 'EDM', 'Life of Pablo Tour', 'Igor Tour', 
            'Thugger', 'Playboi Carti', 'Cactus Jack', "WAKE UP MR WEST, OH HE'S UP", 
            'Future', 'Denzel', 'LORDE PRETTY FLACKO JOYDE', 'AstroWorld ', 
            'Daytona Tour', 'Children of the Korn', 'Rock', 'Classics', 'Floyd', 'Chill Rock'], 
        'Total Number of Songs Analyzed': '27334', 'Data Lifecycle': '2020-01-24 19:37 to 2021-01-25 20:52'
    }
print(json.dumps(body))
```

That produces the output in the correct format

```
{"Username": "bobsmith123", "Display Name": "Bob Smith", "Account Creation Date": "2016-10-10", "Following": "34", "Followers": "46", "Number of playlists": "32", "Playlist names": ["5th Dimension", "Dumb Chilling", "Rock v2 / Nu Metal", "Party \ud83c\udf7b", "Rap", "Pumping Iron", "Aggression", "Soundcloud 4", "Oldies but Goodies", "Chopped and Screwed", "Cruel Winter", "Soundcloud", "Halloween 2020", "Trap Christmas", "80's Night", "EDM", "Life of Pablo Tour", "Igor Tour", "Thugger", "Playboi Carti", "Cactus Jack", "WAKE UP MR WEST, OH HE'S UP", "Future", "Denzel", "LORDE PRETTY FLACKO JOYDE", "AstroWorld \ud83c\udfa2\ud83c\udfa1\ud83c\udfa0", "Daytona Tour", "Children of the Korn", "Rock", "Classics", "Floyd", "Chill Rock"], "Total Number of Songs Analyzed": "27334", "Data Lifecycle": "2020-01-24 19:37 to 2021-01-25 20:52"}
```

and as a bonus you get escaped unicode characters.